# Resizing and copying elements in a Hashtable Array

Tags: c++, hashmap

Right now I have struct `IndexLocation` that defines a page number `pageNum` and a word number `wordNum` on a page, and a struct `IndexRecord` that consists of a specific word and its `locations` that is a vector of `IndexLocations`.

In IndexRecord.h:

```
struct IndexLocation {
    int pageNum; //1 = first page
    int wordNum; //1 = first word on page

    IndexLocation(int pageNumber, int wordNumber);
};

struct IndexRecord {
    //indexed word
    std::string word;
    //list of locations it appears
    std::vector<IndexLocation> locations;

    IndexRecord();

    //Constructor - make a new index record with no locations
    explicit IndexRecord(const std::string& wordVal);

    //Add an IndexLocation to the record
    // Does NOT check for duplicate records
    void addLocation(const IndexLocation& loc);

    //Returns true if the record contains the indicated location
    bool hasLocation(const IndexLocation& loc) const;
};
```

Then, I have a Hash Map `IndexMap` which stores values of `IndexRecords` using the `word` as the key. Within one, an `IndexRecord` may be stored at `bucket` 3, have a `word` apple, and have `locations` be 1,2 and 2,5.

```
#include "IndexRecord.h"
class IndexMap
{
private:
    int numBuckets;
    int keyCount;
    IndexRecord* buckets;

    //handle resizing the hash table into a new array with twice as many buckets
    void grow();

    //Get the location this key should be placed at.
    //  Will either containt IndexRecord with that key or an empty IndexRecord
    unsigned int getLocationFor(const std::string& key) const;

public:
    //Construct HashMap with given number of buckets
    IndexMap(int startingBuckets = 10);

    //Destructor
    ~IndexMap();

    //Copy constructor and assignment operators
    IndexMap(const IndexMap &other);
    IndexMap& operator=(const IndexMap& other);

    //Returns true of indicated key is in the map
    bool contains(const std::string& key) const;

    //Add indicated location to the map.
    //  If the key does not exist in the map, add an IndexRecord for it
    //  If the key does exist, add a Location to its IndexRecord
    void add(const std::string& key, int pageNumber, int wordNumber);

    void IndexMap::add2(const std::string &key, IndexLocation location)
};
```

Furthermore, in IndexMap.cpp, I have the `add` function, the `add2` function, and `grow` function.

```
void IndexMap::add(const std::string &key, int pageNumber, int wordNumber) {
    if (keyCount == numBuckets)
        grow();

    int bucketNumber = getLocationFor(key);

    if (this->contains(key) == true)
        buckets[bucketNumber].addLocation(IndexLocation(pageNumber, wordNumber));
    else if (this->contains(key) == false) {
        while (buckets[bucketNumber].word != "?") {
            if (bucketNumber < numBuckets)
                bucketNumber++;
            else if (bucketNumber == numBuckets)
                bucketNumber = 0;
        }

        string foo = key;
        buckets[bucketNumber].word = key;
        buckets[bucketNumber].addLocation(IndexLocation(pageNumber, wordNumber));
        keyCount++;
    }
    return;
}

void IndexMap::add2(const std::string &key, IndexLocation location) {
    if (keyCount > 0.7 * numBuckets)
        grow();

    int bucketNumber = getLocationFor(key);

    if (this->contains(key) == true)
        buckets[bucketNumber].addLocation(location);
    else if (this->contains(key) == false) {
        while (buckets[bucketNumber].word != "?") {
            if (bucketNumber < numBuckets)
                bucketNumber++;
            else if (bucketNumber == numBuckets)
                bucketNumber = 0;
        }

        string foo = key;
        buckets[bucketNumber].word = key;
        buckets[bucketNumber].addLocation(location);
        keyCount++;
    }
    return;
}

void IndexMap::grow() {
    IndexRecord* oldTable = buckets;
    int oldSize = numBuckets;
    numBuckets = numBuckets * 2 + 1;
    IndexRecord* newArray = new IndexRecord[numBuckets];
    keyCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < oldSize; i++) {
        if (oldTable[i].word != "?") {
            this->add2(oldTable[i].word, oldTable[i].locations[i]); // having trouble here
        }
    }
    buckets = newArray;
    delete [] oldTable;
}
```

My issue begins here. I believe my basic logic is sound: keep the old array around with a pointer, make a new, larger one and reset the size of the HashTable, iterate through the old array and add anything it contains back into the hashtable with the add function, and then delete the old array, but this just results in a segmentation fault (SIGSEGV) once `keyCount` hits `numBuckets`. (The reason I have an `add2` function which is almost identical to my `add` function and use it in `grow` is because I didn't know how to modify get a `pageNumber` and a `wordNumber` for the `this->add2` line within `grow`; the assignment specifications say we cannot modify the original `add` function's header).

Answer (score 0):

You never assign to `buckets` in `grow`, so the newly enlarged array is not accessible by your other functions.

Comment: By that, do you mean having something like ```buckets = newArray;``` at the end?

Comment: @Logan87654321 You should have it right after your assignment to `newArray`, because `add2` needs to access the new array.